# Bulk insert in JPA eclipselink

Tags: database, jpa, bulkinsert

I need bulk insert of a list in database using in JPA where I'm having list of object about 35 size, I want to insert as bulk is there any options in JPA?

I've tried dis coding for bulk insert

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        for (int i = 0; i < batchList.size(); i++) {
            // Getting the object from the list by using loop
            BatchInfo batchInfo = batchList.get(i);
            em.persist(batchInfo);
        }

        em.getTransaction().commit();
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

but I'm getting exception like this,

> During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship
>   that was not marked cascade PERSIST: com.cation.bean.Users@15655c9.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete rows in a batch using JPA EntityManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501338/delete-rows-in-a-batch-using-jpa-entitymanager)

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that one of your objects is referencing another new object that has not been persisted yet.

Either mark the relationship as cascade persist, or persist the related object first.

You could also set the persistence unit property, "eclipselink.persistence-context.commit-without-persist-rules"="true", which will always cascade persist when required.